# Variable Changing Value On It's Own Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have formatted a string to be used within a putItem call using DynamoDB SDK. This Long string (item I would like to add has lots of information) is stored in a variable and I should be able to use it within the `Item {}` part of `dynamoDdb.putItem()` .

However, when the variable is actually processed extra characters are added in causing the formatting to be incorrect for how an `Item {}` should look.

See below:

```
itemToAdd = JSON.stringify(marshalled2, null,2)
newString = itemToAdd.slice(4, itemToAdd.length-1)
correct = newString.replaceAll(" ", '');
correct2 = correct.replaceAll("\n", "")
//console.log(newString)
var params = {
   TableName: "Music",
   Item: {
      correct2
   }
}

            dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Success", data);
                }
            });
```

My issue is that the string `correct2` has no slashes or `\n` in it as I have removed them prior however when the string correct2 is used with the params object extra black slashes have been added into the string messing up the formatting.

An example of the string contained in correct2 would be as follows:

```
"AlbumData":{"S":"2B5C1828-6077-4ED1-89AD-13602A7AC08D"},"label":{"S":"EvolutionMediaMusic"},"Album":{"S":"BleakDrama"},"albumCode":{"S":"EMM101"},"releaseDate":{"S":"21/06/2016"},"description":{"S":"Contemporarynoircrimedrama:coldandforebodingcueswithtwistedsyntheticatmospheresandpulsingrhythms."},"credits":{"S":""},"tracks":{"L":[{"M":{"id":{"S":"984CA56C-3FA8-4F49-9C9E-3F96C237EE7E"},"trackNo":{"S":"1"},"albumCode":{"S":"EMM101"},"albumName":{"S":"BleakDrama"},"lengthOfTrack":{"S":"02:30"}, //more fields would go here
```

If I was to copy the text above and insert it into where the variable is there is no issue with the code. Using the javascript debug console the variable correct2 is set to the above however
`params.Item = \"AlbumData\":{\"S\":\"2B5C1828-6077-4ED1-89AD-13602A7AC08D\"},\"label\":{\"S\":\"EvolutionMediaMusic\"},\"Album\":{\"S\":\"BleakDrama\"}, // and the patten repeats`

What is causing the difference between correct2 and params.Item? I would expect them to be the same.

Comment: Why are you supplying a manually-hacked JSON string for the Item? Just use native JS objects. See a good example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html#dynamodb-example-table-read-write-writing-an-item).

Comment: It is because putItem does not allow for JS objects to be passed into it. The correct way to do this is to use “Put” Instead and you have to create a “Document.Client” as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Comment: That's not correct. You don't have to provide a JSON string for the item, regardless of whether you use the base DynamoDB client or the DocumentClient. The base client example of [put_item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) shows the use of a regular JS object with attribute values, for example.

Comment: In the link you have shown within Item that is not a normal JS Object. In their example it is DynamoDB JSON object as the attributes have their types declared. Within Normal JSON objects there is no need to declare types of the attributes.

Comment: You misunderstand what JSON is. In the [put_item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property)  example, those are completely vanilla JavaScript object literals, whether or not they have the intermediate type (e.g. "S" or "N") that is required for low-level DynamoDB items, and whether or not their keys are double-quoted e.g. "AlbumTitle" (quotes are optional in JS object literals unless the key is a reserved word or contains whitespace or special characters). JSON is a data-interchange format, essentially a string, where all keys must be quoted.

Comment: To clarify, within JavaScript source code `{ name: "Amrik" }`, `{ "name": "Amrik" }`, `{ name: { S: "Amrik" } }`,  and `{ "name": { "S": "Amrik" } }` are all valid JavaScript object literals. Those with the "S" (the 3rd and 4th examples) are how you indicate values to the low-level DynamoDB client, but they are still JS object literals, not JSON strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, its ok, just relax. Its called escaping

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-escape-characters-to-correctly-log-quotes-in-a-string-using-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for that second article it explains the escaping very well.